# Professional Edition Trial Version Limitations

Tags: workflow, approval-process, professional-edition, enterprise, trial

Currently I'm on Enterprise Trial Version (30 days) edition of Salesforce.  I want to move to Professional Edition!  Salesforce account manager has confirmed that they cannot downgrade to Professional Edition!

1) Now, if I create a new Professional Edition Trial Version, can I move all the configuration that I did in my enterprise trial version to the new professional trial version?  What options do I have for the migration?  Can I deploy packages to professional edition?

2) I read in all the documents, that there are no workflows, approval process for professional edition. I also read (from salesforce account manager) that there are 3 workflows available in professional.  Can anyone confirm using workflows / approval process in professional edition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The new Professional editions of Salesforce comes with Process Builders etc.

https://www.salesforce.com/blog/2016/02/new-editions-2016.html

Answers to my own questions

1. Unless API is enabled in Professional Edition, we cannot use packages/force.com IDE.  And enabling it is not free.
2. The newest editions have Process Builder features. Great!

Answer (score 2):

1) For the migration you would need to use a tool like the [Salesforce deployment tool](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=code_tools_ant_using.htm&language=en_US) though this may mean having to get the API access enabled in the Professional Edition trial org. It may be that Salesforce can assist on this or have another way of doing it as they do have types of access that we as customers or consultants can not use.

If you have packages from the AppExchange I'd recommend installing them from the AppExchange into the new SF Org rather than trying to migrate with a tool.

2) According to [Salesforce's documentation](https://www.salesforce.com/assets/pdf/datasheets/DS_SalesCloud_EdCompare.pdf) no workflows or approval processes are supported in Professional Edition even as an additional cost feature but your Account Executive might know of something else which applies here so it would be worth really checking with them on it.

It has been a little while since I've worked on a Professional Edition Org so I can see that the new lightning edition adds Record Types and Developer Sandboxes and also lists 5 processes but I'll have to keep looking to see what these are.

Comment: Can you post a link to the Salesforce deployment tool? I would also suggest using the Force.com migration tool (https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Force.com_Migration_Tool)

Comment: Account executive is more interested in selling the enterprise edition than giving us info on professional

Comment: @sfdcFanBoy unfortunately I don't have any tools for Account Executive management.  Enterprise Edition is more capable but it is quite a bit more expensive so if you only need Professional Edition's capabilities then you need to stay firm in negotiation.